# Can I be schooled in Necromancy but still choose powers that have the Nethermancy description?

Tags: dnd-4e, necromancy

I'm currently going through the **Heroes of Shadow** manual, and seeing how I'm still new to wizards, is it possible to be associated with the **Necromancy** school, yet still choose spells that have the '**Nethermancy**' keyword?

Or am I limited to only use **Necromancy** spells?

The reason I ask is, for when I have to choose more than one daily or utility spell per allowed level (*spellbook*), I'd like to keep it in the shadow schools..

Answer (score 2):

**You can choose any wizard powers you want, including Nethermancy powers.**

Choosing the necromancy specialization does *not* restrict you from learning/casting Nethermancy spells (or any other kind of wizard spells). It gives you bonuses when casting necromancy spells, and obviously you won't get those bonuses on Nethermancy spells, but you can still *use* Nethermancy spells. In fact, if you wanted, you could take *only* Nethermancy spells (though at that point you should probably just make a Nethermancer).